# Post Thumbnail not showing on homepage with error <img src="&lt;!--Can't find substitution for tag [post.thumbnailUrl]--&gt;"

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

can anybody help? thumbnail not showing on my blogger post and showing following error in inspect element : Can't find substitution for tag [post.thumbnailUrl]

I tried my ways but I can't able to succeed.

Comment: Can you please provide me your blog link?

Comment: @AshishBhanderi blog link is https://www.noxmoviespoint.tk and problem in "latest movies" section

Answer (score 2):

When the images are hosted externally (aka not uploaded via Blogger editor) and you still want to access them via Blogger data tag, then you will need to use `<data:post.firstImageUrl/>` in place of `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create blogger blog and I found that you need to attach image to your post.
Then after it will displayed over there.
Please try to upload picture and let me know it is not working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Images hosted on different server otherwise blogger host don't be considered in `Blog1` widget.

You have to upload image inside post instead of including its source from another host.
[image]